# how create a flag with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, easeljs

i find a simple canvas flag, but I have the question of how can I make it with **EaselJS**?
because in EaselJS documentation don't says about, make another canvas *"without DOM interaction"*, and change pixel positions, but in **EaselJS** documentation I can't find how make it, and I have some questions:

1 Can i merge **EaselJS** code with normal Canvas code? Explanation, If I draw an animated North Korean flag star with some textures, can I make the static draw with **EaselJS**, and animate it with naked canvas code?

2 is possible make it with other library?, such as **LimeJS** or other libraries

3 I **must** use a **WEBGL Library**?, such as Three.js?

Comment: Haven't used the library, but from the docs it looks like EaselJS is a library that does stuff to the canvas when you call stage.update(). In that case I don't see why you couldn't alter the canvas yourself as well after calling that.

Comment: It must be asked: why the north korean flag?-)